Systemctl unit fails on "Requisite", but still executes "ExecStart" command
I'm trying to create a systemctl unit, that will only start if another one is active. As far as i know, it can be done by specifying a Requisite field. Thus, i've configured my unit like so:
[Unit]
Description=Force clients with mismatching IPs to reconnect
Requisite=openvpn@server.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/openvpn/kicker/kicker.py
TimeoutSec=15

However, when i used systemctl stop openvpn@server and systemctl start my-unit, i got the following logs:
Starting openvpn-kicker.service - Force clients with mismatching IPs to reconnect...
Dependency failed for openvpn-kicker.service - Force clients with mismatching IPs to reconnect.
openvpn-kicker.service: Job openvpn-kicker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
kicker.py[1026]: Traceback (most recent call last):
kicker.py[1026]:   File "/etc/openvpn/kicker/kicker.py", line 16, in <module>
kicker.py[1026]:     manage.connect(Manage_Path)
kicker.py[1026]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
openvpn-kicker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

So, basically, unit fails at requirements check, but then executes a script in "ExecStart" anyway - hence the python errors. Is it intended to work that way, and i've got something wrong, or is it a bug? If relevant, OS is Ubuntu 22.04

First, note that requirement dependencies and ordering dependencies are orthogonal in systemd. A unit can have a weak/mild/strong requirement on another (Wants, Requires, Requisite, etc.), but ordering has to be specified separately using Before/After. Think of it like this:

Wants=foo: when I am being started, ask foo to be started as well, but I don't really care what happens to it.
Requires=foo: when I am being started, ask foo to be started as well, and if foo's startup fails, then consider my startup to have failed too, irrespective of the status of the actual actions taken for my startup.
Requisite=foo: when I am being started, foo must already have been started. If not, consider my startup to have failed, irrespective of the status of the actual actions taken for my startup.

So, I can have a service A that Requires B, but may have an ordering of Before B. This can be the case when B is doing something general that can be done independently of A, but A always wants B to do that something after A has started.
And in particular for Requisite, the documentation specifically recommends using it with After:

Hence this setting should usually be combined with After=, to ensure this unit is not started before the other unit.

The second thing to understand is that jobs and units are separate, but related, concepts in systemd. See, e.g., this answer or this answer for more on that. So when the docs say:

However, if the units listed here are not started already, they will not be started and the starting of this unit will fail immediately.

It means that the job for staring of this unit will fail. But the actual starting will proceed. The way it works is something like this:

You run systemctl start foo, or something else causes foo to be started (e.g., a dependency by another unit, target, etc.).
Then systemd creates a job for starting this unit.

It fires off queries to dependency units about their state.
[At some time before (5)] the query for a Requisite unit that isn't active results in the job status being set to failed.


Systemd waits for jobs for any units that are Before it in the ordering.
If nothing in the ordering fails that is Required, Requisite or stronger, it proceeds with actually running the ExecStart* commands. Note that this means if there are no other jobs in the ordering before it, systemd immediately proceeds with this step.
It reports the status of the job.

This will be failed if a Requisite unit wasn't active, or for a bunch of other reasons, such as failure in actually running the commands, etc.



For the checks in (2.1) to mean anything for the execution of commands in (4), there should be an ordering that systemd will consider in (3). In this case, there isn't.
Quoting Lennart Poettering:

Requisite= without After= makes no sense. you enqueue a check that a unit is started up properly, but then don't wait for the result of the check, but permit the unit you place this in to immediately start...


hi @muru just to be extra clear, the strongest possible options would be: After= and then Requires= or are there other stronger combinations too? Where if the first condition is not met systemctl would stop/exit/quit the service. Basically not run ExecStart. Thanks.

@Jags that ... is not entirely clear. If you have services A and B, what exactly do you want to happen? Have systemd try to start B when A is started, and not run ExecStart of A if B fails to start? Then Requires=B and After=B in A. Have systemd only check if B is started, but not try to start B, and not run A's ExecStart is B isn't started already, then Requisite=B and After=B.

that cleared up, thank you.
